# StarTech USB 3.0 to Gigabit Ethernet ethernet stopped working on ubuntu 13.10 after a recent system update

Tags: ubuntu, networking, usb, ethernet

The device uses [ASIX AX88179](http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=131;71;112) internally.

I pulled the latest driver from the link above and I still experience more than `50%` packet loss for the device.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that revision `V1.9.0` has a regression which causes more than `50%` packet loss for the device.

After trying out a few other versions, the only version that worked on my Ubuntu 13.10 (running on Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon) was `V1.6.0`, which can be downloaded [here](http://www.asix.com.tw/FrootAttach/driver/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.6.0_SOURCE.tar.bz2). 
I have put the direct link because there seems to be no way to get to it other than playing with the URL.